The background color for questions that match a users tags is very hard to see, could we make it more visible?
Could we get a different background color for questions that match a tag the user is watching.
The current color is light blue and is very hard to pick up on a white background.
Could we try a darker color?
Here is a screen shot of the image.  Notice that the blue highlighting is very hard to see

It looks pretty distinct here. Have you tried playing with the contrast settings on your monitor?
